# VBA EXCEL - Rows(fila).Delete -error 13 No coinciden los tipos

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Estoy trabajando algunas macros en Excel, en donde debo eliminar ciertas filas si tienen valores "", sin embargo algunas filas tienen valores **#¡VALOR!**. Estas ultimas también deben eliminarse.

Tengo la siguiente condición, pero me arroja error "no coinciden los tipos".

```
If (IsError(Range("b" & fila).Value) Or Range("b" & fila).Value = "") then

    Rows(fila).Delete
end if
```

Alguien me puede indicar como puedo condicionar si el valor de la celda tiene #¡Valor! para poder eliminar la fila.

Gracias a todos los colaboradores.

PD: fila recibe la posición en que comienzo a revisar una tabla.

Comment: buscar celdas con valor error puede ser complicado... hay alguna posibilidad de que si la fórmula es error ponga un carácter distintivo para que luego sea más fácil buscarlas? por ejemplo un "-".

Comment: Hola @Damian la celda tiene una formula que compara hacia otra hoja, y de no encontrar resultado deja la celda vacía "", sin embargo si queda con #¡Valor! me arroja error de tipos.

Comment: Puedes utilizar la Funcion SI.ERROR(tu formula;"") y en lugar de #¡Valor! la dejaría vacía también. Así no debes buscar dos cosas distintas

Comment: Es una buena alternativa, lo propondré al propietario de la planilla ya que es un cliente que define sus formulas, para que lo considere. De todas formas seria interesante poder comrprobar si una celda está con #¡Valor! para así realizar alguna acción.

Comment: El tema es que hay muchos tipos de errores y con vba es complicado discernir. Podrías probar primero hacer un `Cells.Replace "#¡VALOR!", ""`

Answer (score 1):

Las celdas con error se pueden manejar sin problema en VBA.

a continuación el código para analizar cada caso

```
' Valida si la celda contiene un error
If (IsError(Range("b" & fila).Value)) Then

    Rows(fila).Delete

' Valida si la celda está vacía
ElseIf Range("b" & fila).Value = vbNullString Then

    Rows(fila).Delete

' Otros casos
Else

    ' Agregar código manejo otros casos

End If
```

PD: Cuando se eliminan filas de una tabla es bueno empezar de abajo hacia arriba para que Excel no se salte filas. Se puede utilizar un loop  así:

```
For contadorFilas = ultimaFila to 1 Step -1
```

Answer (score 1):

En muchas ocasiones utilizar la gestión de errores es una muy buena opción. En este caso vamos a utilizar **On Error GoTo** y **On Error Resume Next**. Este último es más corto y directo.

Cuando la línea **if** hace las preguntas de condición se genera un error y este error aparece justo en la segunda condición:

```
Range("b" & fila) = ""
```

Si el dato es un número, un alfanumérico, una fecha, etc. **if** funciona perfectamente pero si la celda contiene un **#¡VALOR!**, un **#¡DIV/0!**, etc. devolverá un error y el programa se detendrá.

Gracias a **On Error GoTo** podemos gestionar esta "interrupción". Digo "interrupción" porque podemos decir que la función se detiene para solucionar el problema y luego vuelve al principio. Es cierto que no sigue desde el mismo punto en el que se generó el error pero eso no importa, en este caso. La función terminará borrando todas las celdas vacias y con errores.

Los tres ejemplos dan el mismo resultado mostrado en la imagen de abajo.

```
Sub s_BorraRow1()

Dim fila, v_Range As Single
On Error GoTo sigue

    'v_Range = Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row 'Hasta la primera celda en blanco
    v_Range = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'Hasta la última delda escrita

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For fila = v_Range To 2 Step -1
        If IsError(Range("b" & fila)) _
            Or Range("b" & fila) = "" _
            Or Range("b" & fila) = "#¡VALOR!" _
            Then Rows(fila).Delete
    Next fila
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Fin..."
    Exit Sub
    
sigue:
    Rows(fila).Delete
    s_BorraRow1
End Sub
```

**On error Resume Next**, especialmente en este caso, es la mejor opción. Solo hace una pasada y la interrupción por el error es practicamente nula en tiempo de ejecución.

```
'VBA Excel
Sub s_BorraRow2()

Dim fila, v_Range As Single
On Error Resume Next

    'v_Range = Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row 'Hasta la primera celda en blanco
    v_Range = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'Hasta la última delda escrita

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For fila = v_Range To 2 Step -1
        If IsError(Range("b" & fila)) _
            Or Range("b" & fila) = "" _
            Or Range("b" & fila) = "#¡VALOR!" _
            Then Rows(fila).Delete
    Next fila
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Fin..."
End Sub
```

Hay un tercer método utilizando ***Do While*** junto con ***For Each***. La variable **A** hace una función muy importante y no se puede prescindir de ella. Debido al método utilizado no es muy aconsejable utilizarlo si el número de celdas es elevado ya que el tiempo de proceso crece exponencialmente con estas.

```
'VBA Excel
Sub s_BorraRow3()

Dim A As Boolean
Dim v_Range As Range
On Error Resume Next
    
    'Set v_Range = Range("B2", "B" & Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row) 'Hasta la primera celda en blanco
    Set v_Range = Range("B2", "B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row) 'Hasta la última delda escrita
    A = True
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While A
        A = False
        For Each obj_select In v_Range
            If IsError(obj_select) _
                Or obj_select = "" _
                Or obj_select = "#¡VALOR!" _
                Then A = Rows(obj_select.Row).Delete
        Next
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Fin..."
End Sub
```

Si quisiéramos (como en los ejemplos) borrar tambien los errores escritos en modo texto habria que añadir uno a uno esos errores en la forma:

```
If IsErr...  Or Range("b" & fila) = "#¡VALOR!" Then
```

La imagen muestra una celda modo texto que no fue borrada porque el código no incluía esta condición.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]